# Increasing text overflow limit as window changes size

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on a react component and I need to limit the displayed text in a  field that changes based on a input component. I am trying to make it so when the text box input becomes longer than the width of the component, to display what can fit followed by ... . I have something that works but it uses width: field to set how wide the text can go and I am looking for a responsive way to make it fit more or less text

```js
  <span
            className='itemTitle'
            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
            id = 'itemTitle'
            style = {{width: '420px', "whiteSpace": "nowrap",
                          overflow:"hidden !important",
                          'textOverflow': "ellipsis",
                        'display': 'inline-block'}}>
          {prompt || card.get('promptText')} 
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is as follows.

From the parent component which renders a Title Component, I add a ref and on add a resize eventlistener which sends new props to the ItemTitle component.

```js
  <div ref={input => {{this.rangeInput = input}}}>
                      <ItemTitle
                        prompt={prompt}
                        {...this.props}
                        width = {this.state.width}
                      /> 
  </div>
  
  
    updateDimensions = () => {
    this.setState({
      width: this.rangeInput.offsetWidth
    })
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }

  /**
   * Remove event listener
   */
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
  
  
  Then in ItemTitle.js
  <span
            className='itemTitle'
            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
            id = 'itemTitle'
            style = {{width: this.state.width - 140, "whiteSpace": "nowrap",
                          overflow:"hidden !important",
                          'textOverflow': "ellipsis",
                        'display': 'inline-block'}}>


            {prompt || card.get('promptText')}
          </span>
```